# como acceder a una vista por medio de un token

Tags: php

no tengo mucho conocimiento de token
pero ¿como puedo acceder a una vista en mvc con un token? 
Lo que quiero hacer es que como voy a relacionar 2 sistemas en mi sistema 1 tengo mi pdf y quier ver ese mismo pdf en el sistema 2 pero si estoy iniciado de session en el sistema 2 no me pida usuario y contraseña solo para esa vista, es en mvc, la url q le doy es base_url + controlador, no se si me explique bien

Answer (score 1):

¿A qué te refieres con dos sistemas? ¿dos aplicaciones? ¿comparten base de datos?
Creo que la BD de datos del *sistema 2*, si es independiente, es decir el sistema en el que no te logueas, deberá recibir el token de alguna forma en el momento que el usuario se logue en el sistema 1, para así permitir el acceso al recurso.

#### Ejemplos

Voy a exponer dos posibles casos:

- ***2 aplicaciones con una base de datos común.***
- ***2 aplicaciones con bases de datos independientes***

Ambos casos tienen una parte común. Primero, al hacer login el usuario en App1, se almacena un token en una tabla de la BD a la que tiene acceso App2. Se genera en App1 una URL de acceso al recurso de App2, la cual, incluye el token.

El token es de un sólo uso, por lo que deberá eliminarse o marcarse de alguna manera al ser utilizado y se renovará con cada inicio de sesión, asimismo puede establecerse una caducidad.

Al usar la URL generada, en App2 se extrae el token y se comprueba contra la BD para permitir o no acceder al recurso.

**Particularidades del caso 2: 2 aplicaciones con bases de datos independientes**

El token se genera en App1, pero debe almacenarse en App2. Para esto se puede acceder a la BD de datos de App2 desde App1, o más comúnmente, ser enviado a App2 de alguna manera, en cuyo caso a la recepción en App2, se almacena en su BD.

***Variante del caso 2***

Puede ser que el token se almacene en la BD de App1. App2 debe comprobar el token para dar acceso al recurso, por lo que una vez usada la URL con el token, o bien realiza una consulta directamente contra la BD de App1 o envía el token de alguna manera a App1 para que sea verificado en esta y se le dé una respuesta.

Comment: Si, seria 2 aplicaciones, con base de datos en común, lo que no se es como generar el token por ejemplo:http://ejemplo/controlador/funcion/?id=2, eso es en mi app1, en mi app2 la url es diferente me imagino que seria algo como http://token/controlador/funcion/?id=2 ya que con el token aunque no este con una session en mi app1 pueda entrar nadamas a acceder a la vista

Comment: Seria como hacerla publica y como hay relación entre las 2 aplicaciones pues le mando el id para abrir  el pdf

Comment: @Juan Jose, te dejo unos enlaces de como crear un sistema de protección CSRF en PHP, mediante el uso de tokens, creo que podrían servirte para lo que tratas de hacer: http://mac-mix.blogspot.com/2015/02/sistema-contra-csrf.html   http://mac-mix.blogspot.com/2015/02/sistema-contra-csrf-una-vuelta-de-tuerca.html   http://mac-mix.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/proteccion-csrf-iii-corrigiendo-errores.html